# Generics cannot explicitly convert type

Tags: c#, generics

For background I mainly program in Java and am trying to work with/learn generics in a C# project and got stuck.

Here is my problem.  From the main method you can see I am trying to set the soldiers task, but I'm getting the error,

```
cannot convert from 'TaskHeal' to 'TaskBase<SoldierBase>'
```

It seems that this cast should work as TaskHeal is a child of TaskBase, but it doesn't.  Here is my complete code:

```
public class Main {
    static void main(string[] args) {
        SoldierMedic myMedic = new SoldierMedic();
        myMedic.setTask(new TaskHeal(myMedic)); // Problem!
    }
}


public class SoldierBase {

    private TaskBase<SoldierBase> currentTask;
    public int status;

    public void setTask(TaskBase<SoldierBase> newTask) {
        this.currentTask = newTask;
    }
}


public class SoldierMedic : SoldierBase {
    public int healRate = 45;
}


public abstract class TaskBase<T> where T : SoldierBase {

    protected T soldier;

    public TaskBase(T unit) {
        this.soldier = unit;
        this.soldier.status = 1;
    }

    public abstract void preformTask();
}


public class TaskHeal : TaskBase<SoldierMedic> {

    public TaskHeal(SoldierMedic unit) : base(unit) { }

    public override void preformTask() {
        this.soldier.healRate++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though `SoldierMedic` inherits from `SoldierBase` this does not mean that `TaskBase<SoldierMedic>` inherits from `TaskBase<SoldierBase>` - it does not. So `TaskHeal` does not inherit from `TaskBase<SoldierBase>` either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind having an additional base, non-generic class for `TaskBase` and `SoldierBase`, you could do this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myMedic = new SoldierMedic();
        myMedic.setTask(new TaskHeal(myMedic)); // Problem!
    }
}

public class SoldierBase
{
    public int status;
}

public class SoldierBase<T> : SoldierBase where T : SoldierBase
{
    private TaskBase currentTask;

    public void setTask(TaskBase newTask)
    {
        this.currentTask = newTask;
    }
}

public class SoldierMedic : SoldierBase<SoldierMedic>
{
    public int healRate = 45;
}

public abstract class TaskBase
{

}

public abstract class TaskBase<T> : TaskBase where T : SoldierBase<T>
{
    protected T soldier;

    public TaskBase(T unit)
    {
        this.soldier = unit;
        this.soldier.status = 1;
    }

    public abstract void preformTask();
}


public class TaskHeal : TaskBase<SoldierMedic>
{

    public TaskHeal(SoldierMedic unit) : base(unit) { }

    public override void preformTask()
    {
        this.soldier.healRate++;
    }
}
```

---

If you want this to look more like c# (using properties, proper access modifiers and casing), you'd do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myMedic = new SoldierMedic();
        myMedic.CurrentTask = new TaskHeal(myMedic); // Problem!
    }
}

public class SoldierBase
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
}

public class SoldierBase<T> : SoldierBase where T : SoldierBase
{
    public TaskBase CurrentTask { get; set; }
}

public class SoldierMedic : SoldierBase<SoldierMedic>
{
    public int HealRate { get; set; } = 45;
}

public abstract class TaskBase
{

}

public abstract class TaskBase<T> : TaskBase where T : SoldierBase<T>
{
    protected T Soldier;

    public TaskBase(T unit)
    {
        Soldier = unit;
        Soldier.Status = 1;
    }

    public abstract void PerformTask();
}


public class TaskHeal : TaskBase<SoldierMedic>
{
    public TaskHeal(SoldierMedic unit) : base(unit) { }

    public override void PerformTask()
    {
        Soldier.HealRate++;
    }
}
```